# cURL doesn't seem to be encoding array in php

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I've been told that by passing an array into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will automatically do the URL encoding for you, but for some reason it isn't doing it for me. I have tried to encode a string myself, but that won't take in the header. When I pass an array in, it isn't encoded.

Here is my code:

```
   $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8888/testrail/index.php?/miniapi/add_case/s2");  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $caseArgs);//$caseArgs is an array from another function
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);




            curl_exec($ch);
```

EDIT-----

```
Here is the array that I am working with:

    /*Function to set the data for each individual test case*/
function setTestCase($cellValue){
            $case[]=array();
        $case['title'] = $cellValue[0];
        echo $case['title']. "<- Title"."<br/>";
        $case['type'] = $cellValue[1];
        echo $case['type']. "<- Type"."<br/>";
        $case['priority'] = $cellValue[2];
        echo $case['priority']. "<- Priority"."<br/>";


        /*$case['estimate'] = $cellValue[3];
        echo $case['estimate']. "<- Estimate"."<br/>";
        $case['milestone'] = $cellValue[4];
        echo $case['milestone']. "<- MileStone"."<br/>";
        $case['refs'] = $cellValue[5];
        echo $case['refs']. "<- Custom Refs"."<br/>";
        $case['precon'] = $cellValue[6];
        echo $case['precon']. "<- Custom Precondition"."<br/>";
        $case['steps'] = $cellValue[7];
        echo $case['steps']. "<- Custom Steps"."<br/>";
        $case['expectedresults'] = $cellValue[8];
        echo  $case['expectedresults']. "<- Expected Results"."<br/>";
        $case['testSuite'] = $cellValue[9];
        echo $case['testSuite']. "<- TestSuite"."<br/>";*/


        $caseData=array(

            'Title'=> $case['title'],
            'Type'=> $case['type'],
            'Priority'=> $case['priority'],
            'key'=> "246810",


        );

        return $caseData;
```

}

Comment: It should be ok - what is your array? Can we see a sample? It needs to be key/value in the same way a regular form post fields would be name/value: $caseArgs['fname']='john'; $caseArgs['lname']='smith';

Comment: cURL won't encode multidimensional arrays. Can You show us the data You're trying to send?

Comment: @RiquezJP - I've attached the array that I am using. Thank you for your help and feed back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http_build_query will do URL encoding on a <strike>multidimensional</strike> array.

Edit: Sorry. Someone mentioned a multidimensional array above and I just got it in my head.

You have a mistake though, in `$case[] = array();`
This line is putting a new array in the first element of the `$case` array. Just change it to: `$case = array();`

Comment: I don't have a multidimensional array